# .then dentro de otro .then y manejo de errores

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo una función asíncrona en una cadena de promesas, y dentro de una de estas cadenas  se ejecutan otras funciones asíncronas. Las pongo dentro de una de las funciones ya que el código depende del resultado de la función anterior. Para verlo mas claro dejo el formato del código:

```
funcionAsincrona1 ()
.then (res => {
    if (res == 1) {
       return funcAsinc1A ()
       .then (resFuncAsinc1A => { //hacer algo aqui})
       .catch (err => err)
    } else { // hacer otra cosa aqui}
 funcionAsincrona2 ()
 })
 .then (resp => { //hacer algo aqui})
 .catch (err => err)
```

el código funciona bien salvo cuando hay un error en la funcAsinc1A ya que es tomado por el primer catch y retorna el error, pero la funcion se sigue ejecutando y se ejecuta la funcionAsincrona2 y su respectivo .then cuando lo que yo quiero en realidad es que si no llegue a ese .then sino que tambien lo tomo el ultimo catch y eso no pasa.

Lo que se me ocurrio es definir una variable con valor true , y a la que le asigno un valor false si entra al primer catch. Luego el ultimo then lo ejecuto solo si esa variable esta en true, funciona.. pero hay mejor manera y mas prolija de hacer esto?

Comment: Has probado usar `async/await`?

Answer (score 3):

Si trabajas en Node, puedes evitar esa cadena de llamados dentro de los then haciendo uso de ***await***, en resumen, JavaScript se comporta como si fuera "sincrono" y esperará a que se ejecute un método para continuar con el siguiente: [Revisa este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/await), await debe ser usado dentro de métodos asíncronos y los métodos que se llamen obligatoriamente deben retornar una promesa, un ejemplo seria:

```
async function llamadoAVariosMetodos() {
    var resUno = await funcionAsincrona1();
    var resDos = await funcionAsincrona2(resUno);

    return resDos;
}
llamadoAVariosMetodos().then(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Para evitar errores de ejecución, puedes usar bloques try / catch / finally dentro de los métodos que uses, así aseguras que retornen siempre algo. Espero poder ayudarte con la duda!

Comment: Amigo tengo un problema algo parecido, este es el link de mi pregunta que hice:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/345071/como-podr%c3%ada-resolver-este-problema-de-promesas-en-node-js , podrías ayudarme ? estaba usando un .then dentro de otro .then , no se puede hacer así ?