# ¿Cómo podría resolver este problema de Promesas en Node.js?

Tags: nodejs, express, promesas

Tengo días con el tema de las promesas, he leído varios *posts*, incluso he hecho preguntas anteriormente aquí para algunos casos en específico pero siempre me sale un nuevo problema, en este caso tengo horas y no he podido dar con la solución.

Lo que estoy haciendo es un registro de un usuario, pero antes valido si el correo ya está registrado en la base de datos, si lo está, entonces no debería hacer el INSERT en la BD. Lo que tengo funciona, pero me he dado cuenta de algo que creo que no está bien.

Me explico:

Este es el código donde llamo a las funciones para validar el usuario y hacer el insert:

```js
const registerUser = ( {user, name, lastName, pass, email} ) => {
  return getByEmail(email)
  .then(result => {
      var exist = false;
      console.log('----->'+result.length) 
      if(result.length>0){ // Si ya ese email está en la BD entonces no hago el insert
          console.log('Entró al If');
          exist=true;
          return(exist);
      } else {
          insert({user, name, lastName, pass, email}) // hago el insert del usuario en la BD
          .then(()=>{
              console.log('Entró al Else');
              console.log('usuario insertadoooooo');
              exist=false;
          });
      }
    return(exist);
      //aquí iría un condicional para saber si la respuesta de la promesa anterior trajo un resultado (existe el usuario) o no.
  })
  .catch(errors => {
      return(errors);
  });
}
```

Aquí están los 2 métodos:

```js
const getByEmail = (email) => {
  return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
    bd.query('SELECT * from usuario WHERE correo = ?', [email], (err, rows) => {
      return (err) ? reject(err): resolve(rows);
    });
  });
};

const insert = ( {user,name, lastName, pass, email} ) => {
  return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
    bd.query('INSERT INTO usuario (usuario,nombres,apellidos,clave,correo)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', ['JULIAN',name,lastName,pass,email], (err,rows)=>{
      return (err)? reject(err): resolve(rows);
    }); 
  });
};
```

Y aquí es dónde resuelvo la promesa en la ruta:

```js
router.post('/signin', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Entró a la petición SIGNIN.');
  console.log('Cuerpo de la petición:', req.body);
  //req.body.password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
  // console.log('--------------------');
  req.body.pass = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.pass,10);
  console.log('PASS ENCRIPTADA: ', req.body.pass);

  try{
    const result = await Users.registerUser(req.body);
    console.log('Resultado finalll: ' +result);
    res.json(result)
  }catch(e){
    res.send('Ocurrió un Error al Insertar Usuario '+e);
    console.log('Ocurrió un Error al Insertar Usuario '+e);
  }
});
```

Aquí muestro una captura del resultado para explicar mejor el problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, el problema es el siguiente:

Si ven, tengo un montón de `console.log()` para ver como se van ejecutando las acciones. Si se dan cuenta, la antepenúltima línea (*Resultado Finalll: false*) se está ejecutando primero que el condicional `else` de la promesa, y no entiendo porque está pasando eso, lo que quiero es que primero se ejecute el INSERT, y cuándo todo termine es que se debería mostrar el resultado, en este caso, el valor booleano que estoy retornando. Alguien podría explicarme que sucede? es como si solo se resolviera la primera promesa, o no se sinceramente que es lo que está pasando. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradecería, gracias de antemano.

[Editado]

Se me olvidó agregar que si no inicializo el valor de `exist` en el método `registerUser` entonces se imprime `Resultado Finalll: udefined`, precisamente porque no se está esperando a que termine por completo esa promesa para mostrar el valor, la asignación que hago que en el `else` no se llega a completar.

[Solución]

```js
const insert = ( {user,name, lastName, pass, email} ) => {
 return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
  bd.query('INSERT INTO usuario (usuario,nombres,apellidos,clave,correo)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', ['JULIAN',name,lastName,pass,email], (err,rows)=>{
   return (err)? reject(err): resolve(err);
  }); 
 });
};

const registerUser = async ( {user, name, lastName, pass, email} ) => {
  var exist;
  result = await getByEmail(email)
  if(result.length>0){ // Si ya ese email está en la BD entonces no hago el insert
   console.log('Entró al If')
   exist=true;
  }else{
   try{
    await insert( {user, name, lastName, pass, email} ) // hago el insert del usuario en la BD    
    console.log('Entró al Else')
    console.log('usuario insertadoooooo ')
    exist=false;
   }catch(error){
    exist=error;
   }
  }  
  return(exist);
};
```

Comment: Me doy cuenta que tú mismo le das a la consulta que te devuelva `false` cuando debería devolver `true` en  el momento de insertar.

Comment: Hola @Synay . Es que el problema no es el valor que me devuelve, el problema es que se imprime antes de que se ejecuten todas las instrucciones de ese .then. la línea Resultado Finalll se debería de imprimir de último, no se si me doy a entender.

Comment: Bueno, es una acotación importante, no devolver false si te hace la consulta de forma correcta. Por otro lado yo no veo que esté mal, mas allá de tu duda del porqué te esta dando así, tiene explicación. Lo primero que se ejecuta es tu ruta y después tu función llamada `getByEmail`, como tu función devuelve un `true`, `false` o si pasa algo un error, te va imprimir eso primero y después mostrará los `log` que haces en la función.

Comment: El problema es el insert que no se termina de ejecutar, es decir, cuándo entra al Else, hace el insert, luego debe imprimir todos los consolé.log,m y luego retorno el False (ahí termina la función), y entonces, luego en el código donde manejo la ruta es dónde debe imprimir el valor resultado final de último, pero se imprime antes de que todas las instrucciones del Else se termine, eso es lo q no veo por qué pasa así.

Comment: Probaste la consulta al revés dentro del `if` hacer el `insert`. Por otro lado, veo algo innecesario en ese `if` el `return(exist);

Comment: Te refieres a mover el insert al If ? Lo q pasa es que en el If verifico, si es mayor a cero quiere decir q ya ese email está registrado, entonces retorno existe con valor true, y si no, pues entro al Else para hacer el Insert

Comment: Obviamente cambia tu condición, Por ejemplo, si el tamaño es igual a **0** deberías hacer tu `insert`, al contrario es porque ya existe un `email` y al final de la condición `return(exist);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes.

**Primero, evitar usar `return` a diestra y siniestra.**

Si el método `getByEmail` es asíncrono y provee `then()` y `catch()`, ¿porqué usar `return` seguido de `then()` (y de `catch`)?

En todo caso, si vas a devolver `getByEmail()`, usarías `then()` y `catch()` sobre `registerUSer()`, y toda tu lógica la escribirías a partir de allí.

Supongamos que tengo una función que devuelve una Promesa, por lo tanto, implementa `then()` y `catch()`, y la misma me devolverá un resultado o producirá un error. Esta sería nuestra función `getByEmail()`. La usaremos para determinar si el usuario existe. (No abordaré la lógica de la BD, sólo ilustraré lo que ocurre).

```js
const emails = ['daenerys@targaryen.com','jon@snow.com']
const getByEmail = (email) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(!email) {
      error = new Error('No se especificó un correo');
      return reject(error);
    }
    let existe = false;
    if(emails.includes(email)) {
      existe = true;
    }
    return resolve(existe);
  });
}
```

En la función anterior, dado un `email` determinamos si existe en nuestra lista de correos. La función devolverá: `true` si el correo ya existe, `false` si el correo no existe, y arrojará un error si no se le indica un correo para buscar. Como puedes observar, en la función sólo uso una sentencia `return`, y la misma la uso para indicar que la promesa sea rechazada con el objeto de error y de esta forma el código que viene después no se ejecuta (no hace falta ejecutarlo). Si no hay errores, puedo ejecutar la comprobación, y devuelvo el resultado con el método `resolve()`.

Veamos esto en acción:

```js
const emails = ['daenerys@targaryen.com','jon@snow.com']
const getByEmail = (email) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(!email) {
      error = new Error('No se especificó un correo');
      return reject(error);
    }
    let existe = false;
    if(emails.includes(email)) {
      existe = true;
    }
    return resolve(existe);
  });
}

// la siguiente llamada mostrará que no existe el email
getByEmail('arya@stark.com')
  .then(result => {
    console.log(`Existe el email? ${result}`);
  })
  .catch(error => console.error);

//la siguiente llamada mostrará que sí existe el email
getByEmail('jon@snow.com')
  .then(result => {
    console.log(`Existe el email? ${result}`);
  })
  .catch(error => console.error);

//la siguiente llamada arrojará un error
getByEmail()
  .then(result => {
    console.log(`Existe el email? ${result}`);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Ahora, esta función es parte de la lógica del método `registerUser()`, y aquí es donde se pone bonita la cosa.

```js
const emails = ['daenerys@targaryen.com','jon@snow.com'];

const getByEmail = (email) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(!email) {
      error = new Error('No se especificó un correo');
      return reject(error);
    }
    let existe = false;
    if(emails.includes(email)) {
      existe = true;
    }
    return resolve(existe);
  });
}

const registerUser = ({ name, email }) => {
  return getByEmail(email)
    .then(result => {
      console.log(`Existe el email? ${result}`);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error);
}

const middleware = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const resultado = await registerUser(req.user);
    console.log(resultado);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

// si bien mostrará que el usuario no existe, el resultado devuelto por await no es ni true ni false.
middleware({user: {name: 'Sansa', email: 'sansa@stark.com'}});
```

Podemos ver que no se devuelve nada a la función `middleware`, a menos que usemos específicamente `return` dentro del método `then()` en nuestra función `getByEmail`.

Si quitamos el `return` que hay delante del llamado a `getByEmail` el resultado será el mismo:

```js
const emails = ['daenerys@targaryen.com','jon@snow.com'];

const getByEmail = (email) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(!email) {
      error = new Error('No se especificó un correo');
      return reject(error);
    }
    let existe = false;
    if(emails.includes(email)) {
      existe = true;
    }
    return resolve(existe);
  });
}

const registerUser = ({ name, email }) => {
  //eliminamos el return aquí y el resultado es el mismo:
  getByEmail(email)
    .then(result => {
      console.log(`Existe el email? ${result}`);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error);
}

const middleware = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const resultado = await registerUser(req.user);
    console.log(resultado);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

middleware({user: {name: 'Sansa', email: 'sansa@stark.com'}});
```

Incluso hagamos otra cosa divertida, en vez de llamar al método `then()` de nuestra promesa, devolvamos sólo la ejecución de la función, y el resultado será el esperado: (result contendrá un booleano).

```js
const emails = ['daenerys@targaryen.com','jon@snow.com'];

const getByEmail = (email) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(!email) {
      error = new Error('No se especificó un correo');
      return reject(error);
    }
    let existe = false;
    if(emails.includes(email)) {
      existe = true;
    }
    return resolve(existe);
  });
}

const registerUser = ({ name, email }) => {
  //devolvemos la ejecución (sin 'then' o 'catch') y el resultado si que se imprime, pero no el mensaje (obvio):
  return getByEmail(email);
}

const middleware = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const resultado = await registerUser(req.user);
    console.log(resultado);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

// mostrará false
middleware({user: {name: 'Sansa', email: 'sansa@stark.com'}});

// mostrará error
middleware({user: {name: 'Joffrey', email: undefined}});
```

Seamos más creativos, y no hagamos la función `middleware` tipo `async`. En vez de eso, como estamos devolviendo una Promesa (la función `getByEmail` devuelve una Promesa) podemos decir que `registerUser` también devuelve una Promesa (`return getByEmail()`) y por lo tanto, se puede implementar `then()` y `catch()` sobre `registerUser`:

```js
const emails = ['daenerys@targaryen.com','jon@snow.com'];

const getByEmail = (email) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(!email) {
      error = new Error('No se especificó un correo');
      return reject(error);
    }
    let existe = false;
    if(emails.includes(email)) {
      existe = true;
    }
    return resolve(existe);
  });
}

const registerUser = ({ name, email }) => {
  //devolvemos la ejecución (sin 'then' o 'catch') y el resultado si que se imprime, pero no el mensaje (obvio):
  return getByEmail(email);
}

// ahora middleware no es async, pero da igual porque registerUser implementa then y catch
const middleware = (req, res) => {
  registerUser(req.user)
    .then(result => {
      console.log(`Existe el correo? ${result}`);
    })
    .catch (error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

// mostrará false
middleware({user: {name: 'Sansa', email: 'sansa@stark.com'}});

// mostrará error
middleware({user: {name: 'Joffrey', email: undefined}});
```

**Segundo: Uso sensato de `then` y `catch`**

En la primera parte vimos lo que significa usar `return` al momento de devolver resultados de nuestros métodos, ahora vamos a ver el uso sensato de los métodos `then()` y `catch` y lo que debemos hacer para evitar futuros errores.

Lo primero es entender la lógica de nuestro programa. El mismo trata de registrar un usuario sí y sólo sí, el mismo no existe en la BD. Asumimos que el usuario existe si ya su correo se encuentra en la lista de correos.

Entonces, vamos a usar un middleware tipo `async` y usaremos las funciones ya conocidas. Y vamos a completar la función de registro de usuario para que realice o rechace la solicitud.

Una forma de hacerlo (usando `then` y `catch`) sería la siguiente:

```js
const emails = ['daenerys@targaryen.com','jon@snow.com'];

// esta función devuelve un booleano o lanza un error
const getByEmail = (email) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(!email) {
      error = new Error('No se especificó un correo');
      return reject(error);
    }
    let existe = false;
    if(emails.includes(email)) {
      existe = true;
    }
    return resolve(existe);
  });
}

// esta función devuelve el resultado de la solicitud de registro.
const registerUser = ({ name, email }) => {
  return getByEmail(email)
    .then(result => {
      if(result) {
        // aquí devolvemos el resultado.
        return {message: 'Usuario existe', inserted: false};
      }
      // si el usuario no existe, lo agregamos y devolvemos el resultado
      emails.push(email);
      return {message: 'Usuario registrado con éxito', inserted: true};
    })
    .catch(error => {
      //si hay algún error, devolvemos el mismo
      // notemos que este es el punto de captura
      // no deberíamos seguir propagando el error
      // con un 'throw' (lo he visto antes)
      return {message: `Error al registrar usuario: ${error.message}`, inserted: false};
    });
}

const middleware = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await registerUser(req.user);
    console.log(result.message);
    console.log(emails);
    // lógica para continuar con la respuesta al usuario
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
    //lógica en caso de error
  } 
}

// mostrará que se agregó usuario correctamente
middleware({user: {name: 'Sansa', email: 'sansa@stark.com'}});

// mostrará error
middleware({user: {name: 'Joffrey', email: undefined}});

// mostrará que usuario ya existe y no lo agregará
middleware({user: {name: 'Jon', email: 'jon@snow.com'}});
```

Como podemos observar, usar `then` y `catch` puede ser un poco enredoso, y es que cuando tenemos mucho código (o el código es denso) podemos perder de vista el objetivo final de lo que deben devolver nuestras funciones.

Mi comentario incial: *Si el método getByEmail es asíncrono y provee then() y catch(), ¿porqué usar return seguido de then() (y de catch)?* se refiere que no veo particularmente útil tu función `registerUser` ya que sólo es un envoltorio para `getByMail`. Y la conclusión a la que puedo llegar es que puedes escribir toda tu lógica usando directamente `getByMail`:

```js
const emails = ['daenerys@targaryen.com','jon@snow.com'];

// esta función devuelve un booleano o lanza un error
const getByEmail = (email) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(!email) {
      error = new Error('No se especificó un correo');
      return reject(error);
    }
    let existe = false;
    if(emails.includes(email)) {
      existe = true;
    }
  return resolve(existe);
  });
}

const middleware = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const existe = await getByEmail(req.user.email);
    if(existe) {
      // aquí devolvemos el resultado al cliente
      console.log('Usuario existe');
      return {message: 'Usuario existe', inserted: false};
    }
    //insertamos si no existe:
    emails.push(req.user.email);
    console.log('Usuario agregado');
    console.log(emails);
    return {message: 'Usuario registrado con éxito', inserted: true};
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
    //lógica en caso de error
  } 
}
// mostrará que se agregó usuario correctamente
middleware({user: {name: 'Sansa', email: 'sansa@stark.com'}});

// mostrará error
middleware({user: {name: 'Joffrey', email: undefined}});

// mostrará que usuario ya existe y no lo agregará
middleware({user: {name: 'Jon', email: 'jon@snow.com'}});
```

Dicho esto, si lo que deseas es tener tu lógica dentro de una función llamada `registerUser` y que la misma devuelva realmente un resultado basado en lo que devuelve tu función `getByEmail`, mi sugerencia es que conviertas tu función `registerUser` en tipo `async` y captures el resultado de `getByEmail` usando `await`. Con eso, tu código se verá incluso mejor.

Espero que esto aclare las dudas que tengas al respecto.

**Edición**

Como te digo en mi comentario, existen muchas formas de realizar la tarea que requieres, todo dependerá de tu configuración y de la forma en que realizas las cosas con respecto a los datos que almacenas en la Base de Datos.

En tu caso, veo que trabajas con SQL, por lo tanto lo ideal (aunque esto puede variar de aplicación en aplicación) es crear una restricción sobre el campo `correo`. De esta forma, dejas que sea la base de datos la que te informe o la que se encargue de rechazar una inserción cuando un correo ya está almacenado en otro registro. Eso evitará el paso adicional de verificar antes de insertar.

Ahora, lo que deseas es poder realizar el proceso para entender el trabajo con Promesas. Tomaré mi ejemplo y crearé un proceso que devuelva una Promesa al momento de insertar el usuario.

Una forma de trabajarlo sería la siguiente:

```js
const emails = ['daenerys@targaryen.com','jon@snow.com'];

// esta función devuelve un booleano o lanza un error
const getByEmail = (email) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(!email) {
      error = new Error('No se especificó un correo');
      return reject(error);
    }
    let existe = false;
    if(emails.includes(email)) {
      existe = true;
    }
  return resolve(existe);
  });
}

const insert = (email) => {
  // la siguiente función siempre inserta un correo en el array
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //simulamos un proceso que dura 1 segundo
    setTimeout(() => {
      emails.push(email);
      return resolve(true);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

const registrarUsuario = async (user) => {
  try {
    const existe = await getByEmail(user.email);
    if(existe) {
      // lógica en caso de que el usuario exista
      // en este caso devolveré un booleano
      return false;
    }
    // aqui insertamos el usuario ya que no existe
    return await insert(user.email);
  } catch(e) {
    // lógica para capturar el error
    console.error(e.message);
    // no se insertó el usuario, se devuelve false
    return false;
  }
}

// podemos usar async/await, ya que insertarUsuario es async
// o podemos usar then/catch.
const middleware = (req, res) => {
  registrarUsuario(req.user)
    .then(inserted => {
      if(!inserted) {
        // lógica para indicar que no se insertó el usuario
        console.log(`Usuario ${req.user.email} no insertado`);
        console.log(emails);
        return;
      }
      // lógica para indicar que se insertó
      console.log(`Usuario ${req.user.email} insertado correctamente`);
      console.log(emails);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // lógica en caso de error
      console.error(error.message);
    });
}

// mostrará que se agregó usuario correctamente
middleware({user: {name: 'Sansa', email: 'sansa@stark.com'}});

// mostrará error
middleware({user: {name: 'Joffrey', email: undefined}});

// mostrará que usuario ya existe y no lo agregará
middleware({user: {name: 'Jon', email: 'jon@snow.com'}});
```

De esta forma podrías hacer la inserción. Sin embargo, mi recomendación es dejar que la Base de Datos se encargue de la verificación de unicidad del registro.

Comment: Hola Mauricio, como siempre dando excelentes respuesta, lo que pasa es que aún me confundo un poco con esto de las promesas y async/await, por eso me vuelvo un 8 cuándo estoy implementando alguna solución. Lo que había hecho antes de leer fue usar async/await como me sugeriste al final de tu respuesta. LA idea de tener 2 funciones separadas era para tener el código mas separado, es decir, una función para verificar el email, y otra para hacer la inserción. El problema surgía cuándo usaba las 2, con el .then, era ahí donde me volvía un 8, pero creo que es mejor async/await para esos casos, no?

Comment: Edite mi pregunta con el código que ya lo había resuelto, si puedes échale un ojo.

Comment: Pues para gustos los colores. Recuerda que Express se basa en el uso de funciones *middleware* que puedes encadenar una tras otra. Yo, y hablo a título muy particular, separaría cada parte de la lógica en una  función *middleware*. Por otro lado, para la verificación de la unicidad de un usuario, la tarea se la delego a la BD, no lo hago aparte. Es decir, si mi modelo de datos en la BD es consistente, es ésta (la BD) la que me debería indicar si un email ya está registrado al momento de insertar un nuevo registro. Saludos

Comment: Hola @Mauricio, en el penúltimo trozo de código, veo que intentaste simular lo que yo intenta hacer, pero el problema es que cuándo hacer la inserción, ese email.push no es una tarea asíncrono, y es ahí donde tenía el inconveniente, si fuese otra tarea asíncrono (con una promesa) como lo tengo yo en la función resgisterUser, como se haría para que no pase el inconveniente que yo tenía? es decir, esperar a que se termine de ejecutar toda la función registerUSer para luego mostrar los resultados o procesarlos en el código donde respondo a la petición ?

Comment: He editado la respuesta para agregar un ejemplo usando funciones que devuelven una promesa. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Según he podido comprobar en tu código lo que te ocurre es que estas controlando funciones asíncronas como si fueras sincronas.
Te muestro la solución con Promesas:

```
const registerUser = ({ user, name, lastName, pass, email }) => {
    return getByEmail(email) // Funcion asíncrona
        .then(result => {
            if (result.length > 0) { // Si ya ese email está en la BD entonces no hago el insert
                return true // Devuelve una Promise
            } else {
                // Funcion asincrona
                return insert({ user, name, lastName, pass, email }) // hago el insert del usuario en la BD
                    .then(() => false) // Devuelve una Promise
            }
        })
        .then(exist =>{ 
           // aqui capturamos la promesa de la funcion insert y si existe el usuario y donde tendrías que hacer el condicional que necesitas

           // Recuerda que cuando finalices tu lógica debes retornar el valor que necesitas devolver y ese valor se devolverá como una Promise. Aunque ya lo controlas con async/await


        })
        .catch(errors => errors) // Aqui controlamos los posibles errores, tanto de la función getByEmail como de insert (en este caso lo devolvemos a la función que se llama)
}
```

Para verlo mas claro, te muestro la solución con async/await:

```
const registerUser = async ({ user, name, lastName, pass, email }) => {
    try {
        const result = await getByEmail(email)

        let exits = false
        if (result.length > 0) { 
            exits = true
        } else {
            await insert({ user, name, lastName, pass, email })
            exits = false
        }

        // aquí iría un condicional para saber si la respuesta de la promesa anterior trajo un resultado (existe el usuario) o no.

    } catch (e) {
        console.error('registerUser --> Error --> ', e.message)
        return e
    }
}
```

Espero que con este código y lo comentado haya podido ayudarte en resolver tu problema, sino no dudes en comentarme para ayudarte.

[EDITADO SEGUN COMENTARIO]

```
const registerUser = async ( {user, name, lastName, pass, email} ) => {
     try {
        var exist;
        result  = await getByEmail(email)
        if(result.length>0){ // Si ya ese email está en la BD entonces no hago el insert
            console.log('Entró al If')
            exist=true;
        }else{
            await insert( {user, name, lastName, pass, email} ) // hago el insert del usuario en la BD              
            console.log('Entró al Else')
            console.log('usuario insertadoooooo ')
            exist=false;
        }       
        return exist;
     } catch(error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        return error;
     }   
};
```

Un saludo

Comment: Hola amigo, ya había dado con una solución parecida a la que me comentas, edité mi pregunta con la solución, si puedes échale un ojo. aunque sigo con la duda en como podría hacerlo usando puros .then (solo para cultura general), porque como el método insert también es una promesa, era ahí donde me volvía un ocho y donde procesaba la petición como que no esperaba a que se ejecutaran todas sus instrucciones.

Comment: @JulianProg, me alegra que hayas dado con la solución. Sobre tu código, yo lo que haría es que el `try - catch` lo modificaría para que estuviera en toda la función `registeriUser` ya que si la promesa `getByEmail` te lanzará algún error no lo capturarías. Por lo demás me parece bien. Ten en cuenta lo que comenta @MauricioContreras, ya que es muy buena la explicación que nos ofrece.

Comment: Cómo sería? Podrías editar tu respuesta y colocar el código? Si no es mucha molestia claro.

Comment: @JulianProg, he añadido al final de mi respuesta un trozo de tu código poniendo lo que yo haría para controlar los posibles errores.